# How to send a notification at a specific date in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10

I want to send a notification to a user at the first day of the month. How can I do that? It is a notification that is only local not remote.

Comment: First show us what you tried and didn't work

Comment: See please do not reduce the votes of my question. I have been spending atleast a weak to send a notification. All I have gotten is code but where the heck do I put this code. Please I am newbie help me instead of just decreasing votes of questions and making it for me impossible to ask questions in stack overflow. I am sick of this!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you should have this code for notification on a specific date.

```
let alarmTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 24 * 7 - 300) /// you should make changes here according to your requirement.
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday, .hour, .minute], from: alarmTime)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)


let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Notification Demo"
content.subtitle = "Demo"
content.body = "Notification on specific date!!"

let request = UNNotificationRequest(
    identifier: "identifier",
    content: content,
    trigger: trigger
)
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to register the notification swift as

```
   func registerLocal(sender: AnyObject) {
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
}
```

then schedule as

```
func scheduleLocal(sender: AnyObject) {
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = // give the next first date
notification.alertBody = "this is your notification"
notification.alertAction = "be awesome!"
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.NSCalendarUnitMonth
notification.userInfo = ["CustomField1": "w00t"]
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```